# Flex DateChooser - Display Current Date on Bottom of the Calendar

Tags: apache-flex

I would like to display the current date in the bottom part of the calendar on a *DateChooser* control. Has anyone extended the *DateChooser* control to do this?

Something like the attached image...

[image]

I managed to pull off some codes, but still, I have the slightest idea of how to add the label  below the datechooser control.

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.DateChooser;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.core.UITextField;
    import mx.core.IUITextField;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class ExtendedDateChooser extends DateChooser
    {
        public function ExtendedDateChooser()
        {
            super();
        }

        protected override function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void 
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            var dateGrid : UIComponent = mx_internal::dateGrid;

            // Code to add the label here....
            // BELOW DOES NOT WORK!
            /*
            var label:Label = new Label();
            label.text = "TEST";
            label.y = dateGrid.height + 5;
            label.x = 5;
            this.addChildAt(label, this.getChildIndex(dateGrid));
            */

        }
    }
}
```

And in my MXML, I have the control declared as follows:

```
<mx:DateField width="100" parseFunction="{null}" dropdownFactory="ExtendedDateChooser" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this cleanly, what you actually want to extend is the `DateChooser` control, as that represents the dropdown.

You will then need to change the dropdown class of the DateField control

```
myDateField.dropdownFactory = new ClassFactory(ExtendedDateChooser);
```

I'll continue to update this answer as I have time to research.

Comment: I hope you could provide more insight on how to accomplish this. Thanks.